# Converting UTF 16 string to ANSI string

Tags: c#, string, utf-16, ansi

So I have a string:

```
string test = "Checking";
```

And it's being stored as a UTF 16 string. I however want to convert the string into the format of ANSI. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please, take a look at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding

Comment: There's no one "ANSI" encoding - which *precise* encoding to you mean? Note that the result will be a byte array (or similar), not a string.

Answer (score 0):

If "ANSI" is the default code page:

```
byte[] result = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(test);
```

Otherwise you can define specific ANSI code page:

```
int cp = 1250; // e.g. Windows-1250
byte[] result = Encoding.GetEncoding(cp).GetBytes(test);
```